# Weird error when trying to install packages with apt

Tags: apt, dpkg, 20.10

I am trying to install for example mosquitto package with apt
then I do

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
```

and I get an error

```
 dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp'
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I really don't know what can I do to fix it.
Using `Ubuntu Release:  20.10`

Comment: The issue is only with mosquitto? I would restart and try a `sudo apt install -f` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: No, it happens with every package I try to install and the dpkg command returns the same error `dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this problem, all you need to do is

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp
```

and then just run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

IDK why this solves the problem but I guess it's because the file was corrupted...

Comment: this worked for me as well but I found it to be overkill. E.G. initially it attempted to configure a  secure boot password (normally you can have secure boot on is bios without password) and there was no "without password" option. so I had to kill the terminal, reboot, go into bios, turn off secure boot, then try these commands again and then it worked. but I'm pretty sure for one small corrupted file you shouldn't need to reconfigure the entire system. Anyways thanks for this worked for me.